# Angular POST and Web API

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

My code is as the following:

```
    var response = $http({
        method: 'post',
        withCredentials: true,
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(payload),

        headers: {
           'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        },
        url: url
    });
```

where payload looks like this:
{"CASEID":3,"CASENUMBER":"ANY     ","TITLE":"ANY  "}

Backend code:

```
public CL_CASE Post([FromBody]CL_CASE value)
    {....
```

When running it as it's shown value is null.
If I change headers to  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' then I do get value but with properties equal to null/0 . What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call `JSON.stringify`.  This results in sending a *string* to the server, not an object.  And since the WebAPI model binder is expecting a `CL_CASE` object, it has no way to populate that object from just a string.

Simply send the object itself:

```
data: payload
```

---

To be honest, I don't think you need the `headers` option at all in this case either.  Let the default functionality handle it:

```
$http({
    method: 'post',
    withCredentials: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: payload,
    url: url
})
```

Comment: No, I am getting the same.

Comment: @Mark: What happens if you take out the `headers` option entirely?  What does the class `CL_CASE` look like?  When you debug in the browser, what are the details of the actual HTTP request being made?

Comment: Can someone, please explain why it works with no headers?